# Project can't access dependencies in Play mulit-module project?

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.2

I've been trying to separate my Play project into modules. I was following [this example BuildSettings.scala build file](https://github.com/ornicar/lila/blob/master/project/BuildSettings.scala). It was going well -- everything compiled and I had working tests.

After I rewrote one of my controllers in the main project to use the services from the modules I started getting tons of errors.

Play can't seem to find some dependencies. I'm getting this error

```
object ws is not a member of package play.api.libs 
import play.api.libs.ws.WS
```

When I go to that file, it's able to find `play.libs.WS`, but not `play.api.libs.ws.WS`.

My **Build.scala** is as follows:

```
val srcMain = Seq(
   scalaSource in Compile <<= (sourceDirectory in Compile)(identity),
   javaSource in Compile <<= (sourceDirectory in Compile)(identity),
   resourceDirectory in Compile <<= (sourceDirectory / "conf")(identity),
   scalaSource in Test <<= (sourceDirectory in Test)(identity),
   parallelExecution in Test := false
 )

lazy val modules = Seq(mod)

def projectToRef(p: Project): ProjectReference = LocalProject(p.id)

lazy val moduleRefs = modules map projectToRef

lazy val mod = Project("mod", file("modules/mod"), settings = buildSettings ++ srcMain)
   .settings(
     libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
       /* Some dependencies */
     )
   )

lazy val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, settings = Resolvers.all)
  .dependsOn(api)

lazy val api = Project("api", file("modules/api"), settings = buildSettings ++ srcMain).settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      cache, apache
    )
  ) aggregate (moduleRefs: _*)

override def rootProject = Some(main)
```

The **project/plugins.sbt** looks like this

```
// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.3" exclude("org.apache.commons", "commons-lang3"))

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-atmos-play" % "0.3.2")
```

Comment: Have you not changed play version by accident? Could you show us your build definition?

Comment: Have definitely not changed play version.

Comment: And the play version you're using is 2.2? Can you also add `project/plugins.sbt`?

Comment: Added the plugins.sbt.

Comment: looks like you have a play java project, not play scala

Comment: Transitioning to scala. It's about half and half now. Should still be able to access the `play.api.libs` though. I haven't had a problem until now, now that I'm trying to split the project into modules. The main project doesn't give errors for those imports until I add `.dependsOn(api)`.

Comment: Probably a scala project depends on a java project with your changes

Comment: Could you show your project structure? `tree` or similar output. In the meantime I'm gonna answer your question with a smaller `Build.scala` build definition (hope no one objects).

Comment: You were right. I had a dependency on `play-test 2.3-M1` which was was importing `Play 2.3-M1` files, so there were conflicting definitions for `play.api.libs.ws`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `project/build.scala` could really look as follows:

```
val mainSettings = Seq(
   scalaSource in Compile := sourceDirectory in Compile,
   javaSource in Compile := sourceDirectory in Compile,
   resourceDirectory in Compile := sourceDirectory / "conf",
   scalaSource in Test := sourceDirectory in Test,
   parallelExecution in Test := false
 )

lazy val mod = (project in file("modules/mod")).settings(buildSettings ++ mainSettings: _*).settings(
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    /* Some dependencies */
  )
)

lazy val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, settings = Resolvers.all)
  .dependsOn(api)

lazy val api = (project in file("modules/api")).settings(buildSettings ++ mainSettings: _*).settings(
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    cache, apache
  )
) aggregate mod

override def rootProject = Some(main)
```

I don't understand why you're doing the reassignments in `mainSettings`? Could you share the idea behind the `mainSettings`? How do you think `play.api.libs.ws.WS` comes to your project? Who's bringing it in? Shouldn't you add `ws` Play module to `main` or `api` as a dependency?

Comment: It's supposed to specify where to find the source files.

Comment: Well, I do understand the meaning of these settings and what you're doing syntactically, but I miss is why you're doing it. Could you share the project on GitHub so it gets easier to help you narrowing the issue?

Comment: No worries. I responded to one of the other commenters above. The problem was with the dependencies.